# Starting a css site but format issues

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, css-transforms

The link of the site is here progerdevs.co.nf just a test site. When I load the page on my android it is displayed horribly, everything is all over the place. Does anyone know what it is called so it changes when theres a different screen size? I still have a lot to learn :/
By changes i mean for example the images are all displayed verticaly and also the top navigation bar.

Comment: You're looking for responsive design. Try frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for that.

Comment: Regarding the style of your question: I would suggest you to format it more properly so people tend to read the whole thing and find an answer. Think about including images which allows answerers to fully understand your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be talking about media queries.
Suppose you want to change how your site looks depending on a set of screen resolutions like (width)
320px
768px
1024px

Then you must define a media query for each resolution, and put in it all your css rules for any element you want to adapt. Example: you want to change font-size of all your document:

```
@media screen and (min-width:0px) {
    body {
        font-size:10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) {
    body {
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    body {
        font-size:14px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    body {
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
```

Depending on the screen resolution of your device, font-size will change, so you can do the same with any property of any HTML element.

Or you can use Bootstrap, but that requires a deeper knowledge.

Comment: The problem is i am using bootstrap, and neighborhood-guides /thumbnail acts really strange. When i size down the window, the 3 images are really stubborn, changing from 3 horizontaly to 3 vertically, even whens theres loads of space. Im also using col-md-4 for each image, im not sure if this affecting it but what i want is: 2 images made smaller and side by side, and then 1 large image bellow

Answer (score 0):

Yes, better you follow previous answer but here is a quick solution. Add this code and it will work as well

```html
.jumbo2 .jumbotron {
  background-image:url(http://progerdevs.co.nf/elderly.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

I just remove the height;

Thanks